# Number of index per aws elastic domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I was reading the [limits on AWS elastic search service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html). 
What i understand is a [Elastic Cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/_basic_concepts.html#_cluster) == AWS Elastic domain. 
There is a limit of 100 domains per aws account.
Also there is a limit of 20 "data instances" per domain.

What is not clear is, is this "data instance" same as "[index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/_basic_concepts.html#_index)" of elastic search?
If no what is the limit of indexes in one domain of aws elastic search?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, data instance in this context is the EC2 instance that holds Elasticsearch data. In AWS ES, you have two types of instances or nodes as they call it - master & data nodes. Click [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/get-started-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-use-dedicated-master-instances-to-improve-cluster-stability/) for some info on master and data instance

Number of indices you can have in an Elasticsearch cluster is limited by factors such as disk space on your cluster etc. however you need to consider shard size and shard count per node for optimum performance. See [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/max-number-of-indices/97932)